# Button is acting like I'm clicking it multiple times exponentially

Tags: forms, powershell

***Relatively new to PowerShell. May encounter poor practices***

I'm getting this weird issue with PS forms and buttons. I've created a small GUI program that ensures I have installed all appropriate programs before I send the computer out of my office.

In this program I have a section that will bring up an info form. That form will describe the program does, who to contact for questions, etc. Within that form I have a button that will pull up a list of serial number I will need for each program. The Text in the info form is replaced with the appropriate serial information. At the bottom I have a back button to take me back to the original info form. If I click that button the form will return to it's previous state. Which is exactly what I want. But Lets say I want to go back into the S/N section. I will click the S/N button and sure enough it will take me to the S/N section again. That's great! But now when I click that back button the form will switch between the two different texts rapidly. It still ends up taking me back, but when I go into the S/N section again then proceed to click back again this time it will switch between the two different texts for an even longer period of time. I could do this same process all day and the switching back of forth of text will increase exponentially. It's driving me crazy. Here's my code:

```
$Info_Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Info_Form.Text = "Information"
$Info_Form.AutoScroll = $True
$Info_Form.AutoSize = $True 
$Info_Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Info_Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Info_Form.ShowInTaskbar = $True
$Info_Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Info_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Info_Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$Info_Label.AutoSize = $True
$SN_Btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$SN_Btn.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$SN_Btn.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(120,200)



function snForm {
    $Info_Label.Text = "S/N Info Goes Here."
    $SN_Btn.Text = "Back"
    $SN_Btn.Add_Click({
        infoForm
    })
    $Info_Form.Refresh()
}
function infoForm {
    $Info_Label.Text = "Program Info Goes Here"
    $SN_Btn.Text = "S/N's"
    $SN_Btn.Add_Click({
        snForm
    })
    if ($Info_Form.IsHandleCreated){
        $Info_Form.Refresh()
    } else {
        $Info_Form.Controls.Add($SN_Btn)
        $Info_Form.Controls.Add($Info_Label)
        $Info_Form.ShowDialog()
    }

}
infoForm
```

Please let me know what you think. If I am going about this the wrong way please help me better myself. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that you're having is that every time a button is pressed, you are adding another click handler to it.

I've rewritten it using a hashtable to store the different states of the label and button text, so that you can change between them in a single click event.  Now, the "name" of the state is stored in the tag property of the button (it could be saved anywhere, but tag properties are nice for stashing stuff.

```
$Info_Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Info_Form.Text = "Information"
$Info_Form.AutoScroll = $True
$Info_Form.AutoSize = $True 
$Info_Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Info_Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Info_Form.ShowInTaskbar = $True
$Info_Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Info_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Info_Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$Info_Label.AutoSize = $True
$SN_Btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$SN_Btn.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$SN_Btn.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(120,200)

$content=@{Info=@{Label="Program Info Goes Here";Button="S/N's"}
           SN=@{Label="S/N Info Goes Here.";Button="Back"}
           }


function infoForm {
    $Info_Label.Text = "Program Info Goes Here"
    $SN_Btn.Text = "S/N's"
    $sn_Btn.Tag='Info'
    $SN_Btn.Add_Click({
        $newTag=$content.Keys| where {$_ -ne $sn_btn.Tag}
        $sn_Btn.Text=$content[$newTag].Button
        $info_label.Text=$content[$newTag].Label
        $sn_btn.Tag=$newTag
    })
    if ($Info_Form.IsHandleCreated){
        $Info_Form.Refresh()
    } else {
        $Info_Form.Controls.Add($SN_Btn)
        $Info_Form.Controls.Add($Info_Label)
        $Info_Form.ShowDialog()
    }

}
infoForm
```

Comment: Thank you Mike! Is doing something like this considered common practice when creating forms with multiple sections? I ask because currently my program opens up a new form with every new section. I've been meaning to start transitioning to one form with changing content. The information section, I thought, was a good starting point for this.

Comment: Not sure if I'd say "common practice", but it is a good practice to separate out content and logic.